# Airflow - Notification on failure of the whole dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to implement a way to get notified when my dag fails.

I tried to use the email_on_failure and a webhook method ( https://code.mendhak.com/Airflow-MS-Teams-Operator/ ).
But for both of them, I got a notification for **every task** that failed.
Is there a way to get notified only if the whole dag doesn't work?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: By setting {'email_on_failure': True} in default_args would send an email only once per DAG on failed task.  Tasks after "failed task" would be in "upstream_failed" state and wouldn't send any email. So technically it's already notifying if a dag fails because of a task failure. Also, please share your DAG to see why all tasks are sending notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to set `on_failure_callback` on operator level or on DAG level.

On [Dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/25537acfa28eebc82a90274840e0e6fb5c91e271/airflow/models/dag.py#L254) -  A function to be called when a DagRun of this dag fails.

On [Operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c23b31cd786760da8a8e39ecbcf2c0d31e50e594/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L556) - a function to be called when a task instance
of this task fails.

In your case you need to set `on_failure_callback` in your DAG object:

```
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        on_failure_callback=func_to_execute,
    )
```

Comment: Hey Elad, thanks for answering so precisely, I appreciate it.

I actually already use the on_failure_callback with a webhook, but it's triggered at every fail of task and so I receive a notification for every task fail instead an only one for the DAG. Any idea?